# How do I make a macro evaluate some of its arguments?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

I am trying to make a toy system for writing documents using a macro (`doc`):

Example #1:

```lisp
(doc id: 1
     title: "First document"
     "First sentence."
     "Second sentence.")
```

Intended expansion:

```lisp
(make-doc (list (list 'id: 1) (list 'title: "First document"))
          (list "First sentence" "Second sentence"))
```

Example #2:

```lisp
(let ((my-name "XYZ"))
 (doc title: "Second document"
      id: (+ 1 1)
      "First sentence."
      (string-append "My name is " my-name ".")
      "Last sentence."))
```

Intended expansion:

```lisp
(let ((my-name "XYZ"))
  (make-doc (list (list 'title: "Second document") (list 'id: (+ 1 1)))
            (list "First sentence."
                  (string-append "My name is " my-name ".")
                  "Last sentence.")))
```

More sample calls to this macro are:

```
(doc id: 1 "First sentence." "Second sentence.")

(doc id: 1 title: "First document" subtitle: "First subdocument" 
     "First sentence." "Second sentence." "Third sentence.")
```

First come the metadata specs, then sentences. Metadata must come before the sentences. The macro must accept any number of metadata specs.

Evaluating `(doc ...)` should return a string, or write the resulting text into a file. But I have not yet implemented this functionality, because I am stuck on the definition of the `doc` macro (which is the point of this question).

Below is my implementation of the `doc` macro. Vocabulary: `title: "ABC"` and `id: 123` are called "metadata"; `title:` and `id:` are called "metadata IDs".

```lisp
;;; (metadata-id? 'x:) -> #t
;;; (metadata-id? 'x) -> #f
;;; (metadata-id? "Hi!") -> #f
(define (metadata-id? x)
  (cond [(symbol? x)
         (let* ([str (symbol->string x)]
                [last-char (string-ref str (- (string-length str) 1))])
           (char=? last-char #\:))]
        [else #f]))

;;; (pair-elements '(1 2 3 4 5)) -> '((1 2) (3 4) (5)).
(define (pair-elements l [acc '()] [temp null])
  (cond [(and (null? l) (null? temp)) acc]
        [(null? l)
         (append acc (list (list temp)))]
        [(null? temp)
         (pair-elements (cdr l) acc (car l))]
        [else
         (pair-elements (cdr l)
                        (append acc (list (list temp (car l)))))]))

(define-syntax doc
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((doc arg . args)
     (let* ([orig-args (cons 'arg 'args)]
            [metadata-bindings (takef (pair-elements orig-args)
                                      (lambda (e)
                                        (metadata-id? (car e))))]
            [sentences (drop orig-args (* 2 (length metadata-bindings)))])
       (make-doc metadata-bindings sentences)))))

(define (make-doc metadata-bindings sentences)
  ;; Do something ...
  ;; Placeholder stubs:
  (writeln metadata-bindings)
  (writeln sentences))
```

Using this implementation, evaluating example #1 prints as expected:

```
((id: 1) (title: "First document"))
("First sentence." "Second sentence.")
```

However, evaluating example #2 prints:

```
((id: (+ 1 1)) (title: "Second document"))
("First sentence." (string-append "My name is " my-name ".") "Last sentence.")
```

Apparently, the arguments were not evaluated. The expected result of example #2 is supposed to be this instead:

```
((id: 2) (title: "Second document"))
("First sentence." "My name is XYZ." "Last sentence.")
```

What is wrong with the implementation of the `doc` macro? How can I make the macro evaluate some of its arguments?

Comment: you've shown two example calls to the `doc` macro, but you haven't shown the intended expansions for the both of them. showing only the code forces us to both read it to understand the intended expansions and search for errors at the same time. you can make it easier for us by describing and showing the intended results, and for macros the intended result is code expansion.

Comment: @WillNess Okay, thank you for letting me know. I have edited the question (edit #5). Can you check that I have included the necessary information?

Comment: thanks. is (a) `(doc id: 1 "First sentence." "Second sentence.")` valid macro call? is  (b) `(doc id: 1 "First sentence." "Second sentence." title: "First document")` valid call?  (c) `(doc id: 1 "First sentence." "Second sentence." title: "First document" subtitle: "First subdocument" "Third sentence." )` ? (d) `(doc id: 1 title: "First document" subtitle: "First subdocument"  "First sentence." "Second sentence." "Third sentence." )` ?

Comment: @WillNess (a) and (d) are valid, while (b) and (c) are invalid. Metadata must come before the sentences. The macro must accept any number of metadata.

Comment: btw, detecting the metadata from the colon in the name is going to be hard, I think. since it all must go first anyway, it is easy for you to change the format to have all the metadata entries in a *list*. then this macro becomes easier to write.  then (d) becomes `(doc (id: 1 title: "First document" subtitle: "First subdocument")  "First sentence." "Second sentence." "Third sentence." )`. would such change be acceptable?

Comment: @WillNess is it actually impossible when using `syntax-rules`?

Comment: I don't know. was hoping for an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you're quoting `'args`, which results in it being an s-expression after macro expansion, not evaluated with function application. To fix this, you probably want make use of quasiquote. This'll also require you to rework how you specify the macro pattern. I suggest using the `...` notation. Here's a sketch of what I'm describing:

```lisp
(define-syntax doc
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(doc arg rest-args ...)
     (let* ([orig-args `(arg ,rest-args ...)]
            ; the rest is the same
            ))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way, but I've managed to write a helper macro `parse-args` using `syntax-case` in Racket. It works like this:

```lisp
(parse-args title: "Interesting document"
            id: (+ 1 2)
            "First sentence."
            (string-append "Second sentence" "!")
            "Last sentence.")
```

The above gets transformed into a list:

```lisp
'((metadata title: "Interesting document")
  (metadata id: 3)
  (sentences "First sentence."
             "Second sentence!"
             "Last sentence."))
```

Implementation:

```lisp
(begin-for-syntax
  ;;; (metadata-id? 'x:) -> #t; (metadata-id? 'x) -> #f.
  (define (metadata-id? x)
    (cond [(symbol? x)
           (let* ([str (symbol->string x)]
                  [last-char (string-ref str (- (string-length str) 1))])
             (char=? last-char #\:))]
          [else #f])))

(define-syntax (parse-args stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ arg1 arg2)  ; If no sentences.
     (metadata-id? (syntax->datum (syntax arg1)))
     (syntax `((metadata arg1 ,arg2)))]
    [(_ arg1 arg2 rest-args ...)
     (metadata-id? (syntax->datum (syntax arg1)))
     (syntax `((metadata arg1 ,arg2) ,@(parse-args rest-args ...)))]
    [(_ sentence rest-sentences ...)
     (syntax (list `(sentences ,sentence ,rest-sentences ...)))]))
```

Notice how I used a "fender" (`(metadata-id? (syntax->datum (syntax arg1)))`). This is the crucial feature missing in `syntax-rules` macros, which is why I implemented the macro using `syntax-case` instead.

Now that I am able to parse the arguments, all that remains is to use `parse-args` in the definition of `doc`.

```lisp
(define-syntax (doc stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((doc arg rest-args ...)
     (syntax (apply make-doc
                    (group-args (parse-args arg rest-args ...)))))))
```

`group-args` rearranges the list returned by `parse-args` like so:

```lisp
(group-args '((metadata a: 1)
              (metadata b: 2)
              (sentences "ABC" "DEF")))
;; Returns:
;;   '(((a: 1)
;;      (b: 2))
;;     ("ABC" "DEF"))
;; The car is an assoc list of metadata.
;; The cadr is the list of sentences.
```

Implementation:

```lisp
;;; 'lst' is valid even if there is no 'metadata'.
;;; 'lst' is valid even if there is no 'sentences'.
;;; However, if there is a 'sentences', it must be the last item in the list.
(define (group-args lst [metadata-acc '()])
  (define tag-name car)
  (define remove-tag cdr)
  (cond [(null? lst) (list metadata-acc '())]
        [(eq? 'metadata (tag-name (car lst)))
         (group-args (cdr lst)
                     (cons (remove-tag (car lst))
                           metadata-acc))]
        [(eq? 'sentences (tag-name (car lst)))
         (cons metadata-acc
               (list (remove-tag (car lst))))]
        [else
         (error "Invalid values" lst)]))
```

`make-doc` can now be defined like this:

```lisp
;;; 'metadata' is an assoc list of metadata.
;;; 'sentences' is a list of strings.
(define (make-doc metadata sentences)
  ;; ... create the document ...
  ;; Placeholder stubs:
  (display "ID: ")
  (displayln (cadr (assq 'id: metadata)))
  (display "Title: ")
  (displayln (cadr (assq 'title: metadata)))
  (displayln sentences))
```

Usage:

```lisp
(let ((my-name "XYZ"))
 (doc title: "Second document"
      id: (+ 1 1)
      "First sentence."
      (string-append "My name is " my-name ".")
      "Last sentence."))
```

Prints:

```
ID: 2
Title: Second document
(First sentence. My name is XYZ. Last sentence.)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the [`syntax/parse`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html) library, since it's so much easier to write this kind of macro with it.

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define)

(define (make-doc x y) `(make-doc ,x ,y))

(begin-for-syntax
  ;; metadata-id? :: symbol? -> boolean?
  (define (metadata-id? x)
    (define str (symbol->string x))
    (define len (string-length str))
    ;; Need to check that len > 0.
    ;; Otherwise, the empty identifier (||)
    ;; would cause an "internal" error
    (and (> len 0)
         (char=? (string-ref str (sub1 len)) #\:)))
  
  (define-splicing-syntax-class key-val-class
    (pattern (~seq key:id val:expr)
             #:when (metadata-id? (syntax-e #'key)))))

(define-simple-macro (doc key-val:key-val-class ... xs ...)
  (make-doc (list (list (quote key-val.key) key-val.val) ...)
            (list xs ...)))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(doc id: 1
     title: "First document"
     "First sentence."
     "Second sentence.")

;; '(make-doc ((id: 1) (title: "First document")) ("First sentence." "Second sentence."))

(let ([my-name "XYZ"])
  (doc title: "Second document"
       id: (+ 1 1)
       "First sentence."
       (string-append "My name is " my-name ".")
       "Last sentence."))

;; '(make-doc
;;   ((title: "Second document") (id: 2))
;;   ("First sentence." "My name is XYZ." "Last sentence."))

(let ([|| 1])
  (doc || 2))

;; '(make-doc () (1 2))
```